# Google Analytics API not yielding Custom Segments

Tags: python, google-analytics

I am using a Python script to get Segment info from Google Analytics.  All of the built in Segments that come with Google Analytics are printing fine, but the Custom Segments I have created are not showing up.

Here are the relevant portions of the Script:

```
def get_service(api_name, api_version, scope, key_file_location,
                service_account_email):
  """Get a service that communicates to a Google API.

  Args:
    api_name: The name of the api to connect to.
    api_version: The api version to connect to.
    scope: A list auth scopes to authorize for the application.
    key_file_location: The path to a valid service account p12 key file.
    service_account_email: The service account email address.

  Returns:
    A service that is connected to the specified API.
  """

  credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_p12_keyfile(
    service_account_email, key_file_location, scopes=scope)

  http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())

  # Build the service object.
  service = build(api_name, api_version, http=http)

  return service


def get_segments(service):

    try:
      segments = service.management().segments().list().execute()

    except TypeError, error:
        # Handle errors in constructing a query.
        print 'There was an error in constructing your query : %s' % error

    except HttpError, error:
        # Handle API errors.
        print ('There was an API error : %s : %s' %(error.resp.status, error.resp.reason))

    # Example #2:
    # The results of the list method are stored in the segments object.
    # The following code shows how to iterate through them.
    for segment in segments.get('items', []):
      print 'Segment Id         = %s' % segment.get('id')
      print 'Segment kind       = %s' % segment.get('kind')
      print 'Segment segmentId  = %s' % segment.get('segmentId')
      print 'Segment Name       = %s' % segment.get('name')
      print 'Segment Definition = %s' % segment.get('definition')
      if segment.get('created'):
        print 'Created    = %s' % segment.get('created')
        print 'Updated    = %s' % segment.get('updated')
      print

def main():
  # Define the auth scopes to request.
  scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly']

  # Use the developer console and replace the values with your
  # service account email and relative location of your key file.
  service_account_email = '************'
  key_file_location = '*********'

  # Authenticate and construct service.
  service = get_service('analytics', 'v3', scope, key_file_location,
    service_account_email)

  get_segments(service)


if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have **Collaborate permission** enabled for the custom segments you have created

[Manage Segments#Set Segment availability](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6121378?hl=en&ref_topic=3123779#availability)

Visit this link and go to 'Set Segment availability' section in there.
Apply 'Collaborate permission' option as shown in the link.

After this, your segments will be pulled from the API code you posted ;)

---

***Please note:*** Analytics Core Reporting API doesn't have access to the custom segments. They can only be accessed by the Analytics Management API

Comment: how do I use the Analytics Management API?